# Intrinsics - Get only all matching indexes

Tags: c#, .net-core, intrinsics

I'm comparing two vectors `using System.Runtime.Intrinsics` and would like to know the fastest way to get all matching Indexes only.

At the moment my code looks like below:

```
static void CompareVectors(Vector128<byte> first, Vector128<byte> second)
{
    var matches = Avx2.MoveMask(Avx2.CompareEqual(first, second));
    if (matches == 0) return;
    var firstIndex = BitOps.TrailingZeroCount(matches) / sizeof(byte);
    for (var j = firstIndex; j < Vector128<sbyte>.Count; j++)
    {
        var matchingValue = first.GetElement(j);
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

**Problem**:

If first index matches it iterates over all elements in the vector, even if just the first index is a match.

How can I get all matching Indexes only to speed it up?